# how to get checkbox checked when dependent dropdown get changed using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

Here i like to explain my problem clearly

i have a table called `employeedetails`, in `employeedetails` table i have `3` fields `designation`, `company_type` and `relation`

`designation` - `parent dropdown`
`company_type` - `child dropdown`

here `designation` and `company_type` is a `dependent dropdown`, if i change designation it will automatically changes the dependent `company_type`.

here relation field contains a checkbox list like

```
1.father
2.mother
3.wife
4.son
5.self
```

while if change a `designation` it will automatically changes the `company_type`.
for example `company_type` value is `5` get changed by using dependent dropdown.
i need to get checkbox get checked for the value `5`.

here i wrote the code for this, it working when i change the `company_type` dropdown list `manually`, but i dont know how to write for dependent dropdown

`here is js:`

```
$("#employeedetails-company_type").change(function() {
    var value = $("#employeedetails-company_type option:selected").text();
    if (value == '5') {
        $(":checkbox[value=5]").prop("checked", "true");
        $("input[type=checkbox]").not(":checked").attr("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: please include html as well

Comment: please i have updated my question with html code

Comment: Provide HTML output, not server-side code which create it, if possible....

Comment: simple if company_type value get change to 5, i need to get checked checkbox for value 5

Comment: You can use something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/6k6ep8oL/ (not sure about your HTML, but that's basic example of desired behavior)....

Comment: exactly same but not parent dropdown, i need to get it based on child dropdown llist value